# Post method isn't being called with HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, routes

I am creating a simple login page, I have created my login route using nodeJS and my form in html, but whenever I click submit on the HTML form, it is giving me a 404 not found error, although when using postman, the post request works perfectly, am I calling the request wrong?

This is my route in user.js

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length < 1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
          });
        }
        if (result) {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              email: user[0].email,
              userId: user[0]._id
            },
            process.env.JWT_KEY,
            {
                expiresIn: "1h"
            }
          );
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Auth successful",
            token: token
          });
        }
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

and this is my html form:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <form action="/user/login" method="post">
        Email : <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit"><br>
        <a href="register.html">Not a user?</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

They are both located within the same app directory

and this is within my app.js file:

```
// Routes which should handle requests
app.use("/products", productRoutes);
app.use("/orders", orderRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);
```

Comment: Why did you use user/login in action and also is user.js is the main js file of your project ?

Comment: @mzparacha I was using that to try call the login route I created in user.js and no it's just the js file that holds my user routes, I also have app.js and server.js

Comment: did you use app.use('user', loginRoute); in your app.js file, because in your html form i see 'user/login' as your action  while in your router.post() u used only '/login'

Comment: I use 'app.use("/user", userRoutes);' in my app.js file

Comment: and have you exported your server ? from main file like module.exports = app;

Comment: @mzparacha yes I have that at the bottom

Comment: app.use("/user", userRoutes); what is userRoutes here ? can you please tell me how did you declare this variable ?

Comment: userRoutes comes from the declaration in app.js const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/user');

Comment: Is others API are working fine?

Comment: @ChloeMullan is your folder structure is like where the app.js file is placed there is folder name api inside it have routes and then inside it you have user.js ?

Comment: @PavanVora yes, it works fine when inserting this: 'localhost:3000/user/login' into postman

Comment: @mzparacha yes that's exactly how it is laid out, and the login.html is in the same file as user.js

Comment: Try adding this http://localhost:3000/ at the back inside action and let me know does it work ?

Comment: @ChloeMullan Then I'm pretty sure that these both file are not loading from the same server. You can use the same `http://localhost:3000/user/login` in action attribute to your html file it will work as expected.

Comment: @mzparacha when I add localhost:3000 it doesn't throw a 404 error anymore, but it doesn't seem to preform any action at all, nothing in my terminal shows up from me server to tell me the post action has been performed, like it would do when using it with postman

Comment: @ChloeMullan Can you please give me the git code reference or jsfiddle so i look that for you

Comment: @mzparacha Yes of course, here is the git repo: https://github.com/chloemullan3/node-shop-rest-API

Answer (score 0):

You must be loading the HTML file from a different server. If you need to do an XHR request running on either you need to do proxy or you need to use the web address directly.

In your use case using this:

> "localhost:3000/user/login"

in the action should do the trick.

Comment: whenever I do this, I no longer get a 404 error, but nothing seems to happen at all, I'm not getting anything in my terminal either saying the post request has occurred like I would when I do it in postman